# Hypothesis for matrix formula

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I am trying to justify the formula:

$${\rm det} (M) = e^{{\rm Tr}\;log M} $$

for any square matrix M.

My idea is that it is easy to check for diagonal matrices and since det, Tr, and log are continuous functions and the set of diagonal matrices is dense in the set of matrices it must be true for any matrix.

Is that enough?

Comment: How is $\log M$ defined?

Comment: @5xum: My guess is from a series expansion, assuming M positive definite.

Comment: Well, what if $M$ isn't positive definite? I mean, you say you want to prove the formula for any square matrix. Well in that case, you first need to *define* it for any square matrix...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
here the main problem is the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) of $\log M$ that in general, if it exists, is not a single valued function. And note that since $e^A=M$ is always an invertible matrix, the logarithm $A=\log (M)$ exists only if $M$ is invertible, so you have to pose some condition on $M$.